# Can't play SoundPlayer on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, server-side, soundplayer

I am doing website on C# ASP. My task is play a sound file on web. When i did it on my computer (IIS), it was working but when i up my source to server side it's not working, not any fail, it's still complete code but no sound! I wrote code on controller

Any ideas for it, sorry about my English. 
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWjjY.png)

Comment: Please share your code as text with proper formatting.

Comment: Your code runs on the server hosting the ASP.NET application, so any sounds you play there will only play on the host / web server (if at all). If you want to play a sound on the client (i.e. in the browser of the user) then you'll have to use some kind of client side solution, probably using JavaScript or something similar.

Comment: Also, please do not post (links to) images of your code. Instead copy your code and add it to your original question.

Comment: Thank all! Ok, i will post my code in the next time! Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, this won't work this will play audio on the server machine, you need to send your audio to the client and play it on the client side.

[Something like this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)